Discrepancy Between Google Search Console Core Web Vitals and PageSpeed Insights Scores
I'm encountering some conflicting results regarding my website's Core Web Vitals (CWV).
Google Search Console (GSC): Reports 30 URLs failing First Input Delay (FID) and 30 URLs needing improvement for Largest Contentful Paint (LCP).
PageSpeed Insights (PSI): While PSI also indicates failing CWV metrics, it assigns high scores (95 for mobile and 97 for desktop) with all metrics in the green zone.
What I'm hoping to achieve:
Understand the reason behind the different results from GSC and PSI.
Determine the most accurate reflection of my website's CWV performance.
Get advice on prioritizing improvements based on the available data.Here is the website URL [ https://modyedge.com/ ]deeper analysis.
